# UINavigationItem appearing after a few seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I created an Application with a Menu-Structure and want to have a DownloadViewController before initializing the first ViewController.

Therefor i coded in DownloadViewController:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:downloadUrl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    //Doing download stuff ... (still working)

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

The FirstViewController is presented and all functionalities are still there. But the Menu-Icon in the UINavigationBar is first showing after a few seconds. Can anyone please help me?

Screenshots: NavigationBar after View appeared:
[image]
after waiting nearly **20 seconds**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer but just a proposal**

I write here to format the comment properly, try to change in this:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:downloadUrl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    //Doing download stuff ... (still working)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];
        [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: YES, this is working! The Menu-Icon is instantly there. Thank you very much

Comment: @Rogutin Please set my answer as right, I would appreciate it, thank you!